# A suggestion of yes/no button in front of this- "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question? "

Tags: feature-request

I just been getting used to the message - " Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question? " feature. I think its a pretty good idea to make people aware of accepting answers.But here is a small suggestion maybe right in front of it they have like yes/no button to mark as seen and understood or something...i find it a little annoying..there are questions i have not accepted because i thought the answer was not good ebough...and dont want to start a bounty...so dont know if having like yes/no read link button in front defeats the whole purpose...but just an thought...mayebe it shows periodically...instead of just displaying that message right there always

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message automatically goes away after 60 days.

Comment: sounds good...:)